# split a single file to multiple files by key name

Tags: json, bash, jq

I have a huge json file which has its keys starting with a "/". I wanted to create multiple json file based on the key name.

---

```
/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/eula/acceptance
/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/history
/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/nodes
/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/nodes-summary
/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/status-summary
/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/summary
/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/upgrade-unit-groups
/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/upgrade-unit-groups-status
```

---

Following some note in the site, I came across:

```
for f in `cat input.json | jq -r 'keys[]'` ; do
  cat input.json | jq ".$f" > $f.json
done
or when you insist on more bashy syntax like some seem to prefer:

for f in $(jq -r 'keys[]') ; do
  jq ".[\"$f\"]" < input.json > "$f.json"
done < input.json
```

When I tried the above, I get the error:

```
-bash: -/nsxapi/api/v1/vpn/l2vpn/sessions/summary.json: No such file or directory
-bash: -/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/eula/acceptance.json: No such file or directory
-bash: -/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/history.json: No such file or directory
-bash: -/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/nodes.json: No such file or directory
-bash: -/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/nodes-summary.json: No such file or directory
-bash: -/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/status-summary.json: No such file or directory
-bash: -/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/summary.json: No such file or directory
-bash: -/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/upgrade-unit-groups.json: No such file or directory
-bash: -/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/upgrade-unit-groups-status.json: No such file or directory
-bash: -/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/upgrade-unit-groups/aggregate-info.json: No such file or directory
-bash: -/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/upgrade-units.json: No such file or directory
-bash: -/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/upgrade-units-stats.json: No such file or directory
-bash: -/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/upgrade-units/aggregate-info.json: No such file or directory
```

I think its probably bcos, its looking to create aggregate-info.json in the path -/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/upgrade-units/ -- If this is correct, how do I replace the first string "/" in every key to a blank space? Can I get some help, please?

Comment: Since the input file is huge, it would be better to use `keys_unsorted`.

Comment: So, can you please help on how to replace the "/" character in the key "/upgrade-coordinator/api/v1/upgrade/upgrade-units/aggregate-info" to "_upgrade-coordinator_api_v1_upgrade_upgrade-units/aggregate-info" or just take the last part of the key (i.e.) aggregate-info as the file name?

Comment: If you want to create the subdirectories, use `mkdir -p`; if you want to replace '/' with '_', add the jq filter: `gsub("/"; "_")`

Answer (score 0):

It means - to take the first error message as example -, that the directory `-/nsxapi/api/v1/vpn/l2vpn/sessions` does not exist. You could verify this by doing a

```
ls -d -- -/nsxapi/api/v1/vpn/l2vpn/sessions
```

in the working directory, where your script runs.

Note that a redirection to some path does not automatically create intermittent directories.